# Performasure and hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, exception, mapping

I have some pojos, which are mapped to a tables in database.

When I deploy my code into performance tuning environment, I receive bunch of org.hibernate.MappingException due to $performasure_j2eeInfo is added to them by PerformaSure tool.

Is there a way, I can configure my hibernate context file, so this field mapping will ignore mapping error?

SOLVED:
PerformaSure support advised me to put a specific configuration key, to show my pojos to PS and put them in ignored state. I don't remember a correct solution now, but you can find it somewhere online

Comment: Hey, did you fix this? Having the same problem... Thx

Comment: Yes, it was solved with help of PerformaSure support.

Comment: @Vestel: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to get around the issue by modifying the **instrumentation.config** file under the */config/agent-orderride* directory.

Edit the *SafeModeClasses* entry in that file to include a list of specific classes or packages.

```
SafeModeClasses = ClassList(
    include com\.mycompany\.package\..*\.Foo\,
    include com\.mycompany\.otherpackage\..*\./
);
```

Check out page 89 of the documentation here:
http://edocs.quest.com/foglight/558/files/CartridgeForJavaEE_Install.pdf